# ios scrollview with a full screen video as main content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout, scrollview

[this is the layout i want to acheive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMdzl.jpg)

I am trying to figure out how to make this layout work on different screens. i have tried to get the screen height and programatically set the video layer height equal to it. The volume button constrains are 25 from the right margin and 25 from the bottom of the video. The problem is that when i try to run the app the volume button shows in the middle right of the screen instead on the right of the bottom corner. Also the image views are overlapping the video instead of showing up under it. My assumption is that the constrains of these elements see the height of the video layer in the story board, not the height that i set programatically in the ViewController.swift.

Comment: Hi! Just add the constraints of VideoView to Views bounds and not the scrollViews but add it as a Subview of ScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a more coherent layout with a table view and having a section for your full screen video and the rest of the image views in another section. The section for your video will have `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` for the cell height so that you can have a dynamic full screen height regardless of the device.

```swift
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var arr: [[String]] = {
        var arr = [[String]]()
        arr.append(["Video"])
        var imageArr = [String]()
        for index in 1...20 {
            imageArr.append(String(index))
        }
        arr.append(imageArr)
        return arr
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr[section].count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        } else {
            return 100
        }
    }
}
```

As for the volume button, you can create a custom cell for the video section and load it in the `cellForRowAt` method.  Make sure you're using `Autolayout` and not `CGRect` to position it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are working with ScrollView so you need to give each item in you screen a height so you will give the video screen height "Fixed Height" then you will give your button a fixed height as well and connect it from trailing, leading, bottom and Top and I think it will work with you, and if there is any issue appeared feel free to comment with it

Comment: if i give the videoLayer a fixed height it wont show up as i wanted on different iphone screens. like if i give it lets say the height of the iphone 12 pro it will fit the screen correctly but on smaller size iphones just a portion of the videoLayer will be shown. The user will have to scroll a bit to see the entire video. My goal is to make the the entire video play full screen and if u scroll down the rest of the content will appear

Comment: no no it's a scroll view so fixed height won't make an issue for you and you can try it on iPhone 5s to test it with the suitable height, try it and tell me if there is any error